# Integer in MySQL Subqueries in store procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, mysql

I made simple procedure just to demonstrate

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE `demo`(demo_int int)
BEGIN
 DECLARE minid INT;
 SELECT min(id) FROM (SELECT id FROM events LIMIT demo_int,9999999999999999) as hoo INTO minid;
END$$
```

The problem is with demo_int, if i change it to

```
LIMIT 1,9999999999999999
```

it works but

```
LIMIT demo_int,9999999999999999
```

Does not...
It gives error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'demo_int,9999999999999999) as hoo INTO minid; END' at line 4 (errno: 1064)
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem (whether its a bug or a feature is a contentious issue) is that you cannot use that parameter with a LIMIT statement. The LIMIT statement takes integer constants, the key point in this case is that they must be **constants**, **not variables**.

See **[here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8094)** for a submitted bug report, and **[here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,126379,133966#msg-133966)** for a possible workaround which involves using prepared statements.

Comment: But whyy?????????? huh...done with prepared statment... thanks god i'm using MySQL 5.1>